# Center a text in the screen with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to center a text vertically and horizontally on the screen. This is my code

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
         <Text> Header </Text>
         </View>
         <Text style={styles.text}> some text in the middle center of the screen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        backgroundColor:'white',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
     header: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        alignItems: 'center',
        heigth: 80 // this dose not change the header height
    },
  text:{
      //flex: 1,
      justifyContent:'center',
  }
});
```

If I add the flex:1 to text, the header will also be centered which is not expected. I don't know if it's related but the I am also not able to modify the header view height. How can I solve this? The problems can be reproduced on this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/S1urACbJM).

```html
<div data-snack-id="S1urACbJM" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.16);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 33):

This is one way to center text in the screen:

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1, 
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
}}>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        Your Text
    </Text>
</View>
```

And you can also try with position:'absolute':

```
<View style={{
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: 0, left: 0, 
    right: 0, bottom: 0, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'}}>
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}> Your Text </Text>
</View>
```

[image: Your centered text]

Answer (score 5):

I suggest setting the header as `position:'absolute'` , and use `flex:1` and `justify-content:'center'` on the container.

Check the updated style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        backgroundColor:'white',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        flex:1,
        paddingTop:20 //this amount should be equal to the header height so that any items displayed inside the container will start after the absolute positioned header
    },
     header: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent:"flex-start",
        alignItems: 'center',
        position:"absolute",
        top:0
    }
});
```

Regarding the height you just have a typo in the word `height`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions, and I realized the size of my parent element was not become equal to the size of screen dur to some other styles conflicting with it, So, I figured it out by adding the height of View equal to the size of mobile phone's screen height.

```
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';

<View style={{height: windowHeight * 0.8, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: "center", borderWidth: 1,}}>
  <View>
    <ActivityIndicator animating size={100} color="green" />
    <Text>Loading</Text>

  </View>
</View>
```

You can place it anywhere.